# Trying to compare two objects and extract a third object containing their differences

Tags: java, apache, javabeans

I've got two domain objects, of the same type. They contain enums, primitive arrays, and other objects and theres a list in the Heirarchy there too.

I need something to extract a third object of the same type that only contains their differences, almost like a mask that contains only their changes. And anything that hasn't changed be set to null.

Everything points to the Apache BeanUtils, but I cant find exactly what I'm looking for, any suggestions?

Edit#1
Example to clarify : 
If obj1 is the original, and obj2 is the updated version. Then if obj1.value is equal to obj2.value then obj3.value will be null. If obj1.value is not equal to obj2.value then obj3.value will be set to the value of obj2.value

Edit#2
Ideally it should be abstract and in no way need to know what type of object the comparison is being run on. As this could be used for different objects in the future. 
If one of the update values is set to null than it can be ignored as if its not a change.

Comment: What is the difference of two enums?

Comment: If `obj1.value` and `obj2.value` are different, what do you want to store in `obj3.value`?

Comment: If obj1 is the original, and obj2 is the updated. Then if obj1.value is equal to obj2.value then obj3.value will be null. If obj1.value is not equal to obj2.value then obj3.value will be set to the value of obj2.value

Comment: Based on the domain i'm working on, that shouldn't really happen. But if it did then its not an issue if its ignored

Comment: Here is a patent describing a system, which compares Java beans: http://www.google.com/patents/US20070044070 (Probably no direct help, but maybe of interest)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is interesting for me. I searching very much for your goals and find a little library do it. This library is in `google code` and its name is `jettison`.
This utility has a main class with name `Diff4J` that has a method with `diffs` method and by it compare two object and find differents.

Then I write codes for your goals as following:

fisrt define a `Model Object` with name `Bean` :

```
public class Bean
{
    private String  name;
    private String  family;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFamily()
    {
        return family;
    }

    public void setFamily(String family)
    {
        this.family = family;
    }

    public Bean()
    {
    }

    public Bean(String name, String family )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.family = family;
    }
}
```

Then coding a test class as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, 
                                              InvocationTargetException
{
        Bean bean_1 = new Bean("Sara", "clooney");
        Bean bean_2 = new Bean("Sally", "clooney");

        Diff4J comparator = new Diff4J();
        Collection<ChangeInfo> diffs = comparator.diff(bean_1, bean_2);

        Bean final_result = new Bean();

        for(ChangeInfo c : diffs)
        {
            String filedName = c.getFieldName();
            Object to_value = c.getTo();
            Object from_value = c.getFrom();

            BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().setProperty(final_result, filedName, to_value);
        }

        System.out.println(final_result);

}
```

By this solution if you run this code see following result:

```
Bean [family=null, name=Sally]
```

this result is your goals.

**Note:** In last line of loop statement, I used `BeanUtilBean` from `Apache Commons Util` for fill object by `Reflection`.

This utility has a problem, it doesn't support `Deep Comparator`(maybe I couldn't find it) and you have to simulate this task.

for see this library go to http://code.google.com/p/jettison/.

I hope this answer help you.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done without any external library ;)

Let's take a trivial bean

```
public class Bean {
  public String value;
  public List<String> list;
  public String[] array;
  public EnumType enum;
}
```

and add a static (factory) method:

```
public static Bean createDelta(Bean master, Bean variant) {
  Bean delta = new Bean();

  // fields are simple
  if (!master.value.equals(variant.value))
     delta.value = variant.value;

  // enums are simple too
  if (master.enumValue != variant.enumValue)
     delta.value = variant.value;

  // for arrays .. it get's slightly difficult, because arrays may vary in size
  int size = master.array.length > variant.array.length ? 
               master.array.length : variant.array.length;
  delta.array = new String[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if ((i >= master.array.length) || 
        (!master.array[i].equals(variant.array[i]))) {
       delta.array[i] = variant.array[i];

  // same pattern for lists - except we have to add null
  int size = master.array.length > variant.array.length ? 
               master.array.length : variant.array.length;
  delta.list = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if ((i >= master.array.length) || 
        (!master.array[i].equals(variant.array[i]))) {
       delta.list.add(variant.get(i));
    } else {
       delta.list.add(null);
    }
  }
}
```

*(Note - not tested, no IDE/compiler at hand - but it shows a general approach)*

Comment: True, but in this case, the comparitor knows about the beans inner workings preferably it wouldn't care as to what types of objects it was comparing.

Comment: You didn't say that! In that case you have to reflect the fields and the types. And think about java primitives (you can't set them to `null`). And decide, what to do, if a field on *master* contains a value and the field on *variant* holds `null`...

Comment: Apologies, I didn't. Based on what its being used for, it shouldn't really be set to null once its already been set. And if it does get set as null then Its not a huge problem if that gets ignored.